# Make UIModalTransitionStyle Look like push in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I would like to know if there is any way to make an UIModalTransitionStyle have a "push" style ?

Because I have something like this :

```
let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)
let secondViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SecondViewController") as! SecondViewController
secondViewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyle.FlipHorizontal


self.presentViewController(secondViewController, animated:true, completion:nil)
```

But I would like to have the simple "push" effect when I move to another viewcontroller.

Regards !

**EDIT (Thanks to LoGoCSE) But still not solved**

Now I have

```
let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)
let secondViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SecondViewController") as! SecondViewController
secondViewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyle.FlipHorizontal

let transition: CATransition = CATransition()
transition.duration = 0.25
transition.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut)


transition.type = kCATransitionPush
transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromRight

self.view.layer.addAnimation(transition, forKey: kCATransition)

self.presentViewController(secondViewController, animated:false, completion:nil)
```

But, the point is, adding the view (`[self.view addSubview:destinationController.view];`) doesn't work.
So I tried, to presentModalView as usual (Without animation), but The transition is done on the same view, and then, the second view appear.

Comment: Hi did you figure it out?

Comment: I don’t remember sorry, it’s a 2015’s post, so long time ago. 
Now with Swift UI you can do a lot a things, so you should not look for an answer in an old post but trying to find out how to do it in a new way :)

Comment: ok I will do so, thanks

Answer (score 1):

-This code in Objective-C works .You need to just convert it to Swift

```
UIViewController *sourceViewController = self ;
UIViewController *destinationController = objdestinationViewController;

CATransition* transition = [CATransition animation];
transition.duration = .25;
transition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
transition.type = kCATransitionPush; //kCATransitionMoveIn; //,kCATransitionPush, kCATransitionReveal, kCATransitionFade
transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromRight; //kCATransitionFromLeft,kCATransitionFromRight, kCATransitionFromTop, kCATransitionFromBottom

[self.view.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:kCATransition];

[self.view addSubview:destinationController.view];
```

Hope it works :)